# whats the most efficient way to store(persist) array of structure before the application terminates?

Tags: ios, swift

Programming language - swift.

I have created a structure to store all relevant information pertaining to my app as follows. Further, I am creating an array of type wordstruct and populating it with come 3000 entries.

```
struct wordStruct{
    var wordd:NSString
    var meaning: [NSString]
    var sentance: String
    var syn: [String]
    var seen:Int
    var set: Int
    var HF: Int
}
```

After trying multiple methods that I could think of, I haven't been able to store(persist) the data(i.e array of structure).
I have tried NSUserDefault, Plist and NSCoding methods for the same (I may have been doing something wrong.)
what is the most efficient way to store an array of structure ?
can writing the array to a file do the trick ?

Comment: `NSCoding` would be my guess.

Comment: If you can't get any of those schemes to work you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: (Be sure to check all return codes and `error` parms.  They're there for a reason.)

Comment: so whenever I try to do this
aCoder.encodeObject(word, forKey: "word array")
I get EXC BAD INSTRUCTION
Have no idea why ?

Comment: I've seen a few people getting bad instructions from NSCoding stuff in Swift recently. But I'd say that NSCoding *would* be a sensible way to save your data. It may be that you're running into a beta bug. Post your NSCoding solution and show us where you're getting the bad instruction, and maybe we can figure it out. (Incidentally, EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION is usually an assertion failure from an iOS library call; assertions deliberately throw a bad instruction at the processor to stop everything.)

Answer (score 2):

Structs cannot conform to NSCoding, as NSCoding is a class protocol. If you want to use NSCoding to persist your model (it is typically the most straightforward approach), you will have to redeclare your model as an NSObject that conforms to NSCoding.

Here is an example of how you could implement it based on the snippet you provided:

```
class Word: NSObject, NSCoding {

    var word: NSString!
    var meaning: [NSString]!
    var sentence: String!
    var syn: [String]!
    var seen:Int!
    var set: Int!
    var HF: Int!
    // specify how your model will be decoded:
    required convenience init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        self.init()
        self.word = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("word") as! String
        self.meaning = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("meaning") as! [String]
        self.sentence = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("sentence") as! String
        self.syn = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("syn") as! [String]
        self.seen = decoder.decodeIntegerForKey("seen")
        self.set = decoder.decodeIntegerForKey("set")
        self.HF = decoder.decodeIntegerForKey("HF")
    }
    // specify how your model will be encoded
    func encodeWithCoder(coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encodeObject(word, forKey: "word")
        coder.encodeObject(meaning, forKey: "meaning")
        coder.encodeObject(sentence, forKey: "sentence")
        coder.encodeObject(syn, forKey: "syn")
        coder.encodeInteger(seen, forKey: "seen")
        coder.encodeInteger(set, forKey: "set")
        coder.encodeInteger(HF, forKey: "HF")
    }
}

// an example word:
let example = Word()
example.word = "example"
example.meaning = ["abstractions", "generalizations", "use cases"]
example.sentence = "here is how you can implement NSCoding"
example.syn = ["what", "is", "a", "syn"]
example.seen = 1
example.set = 2
example.HF = 3

// persist the example to NSUserDefaults
let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(example)
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(data, forKey: "example")

// load the saved example from NSUserDefaults 
if let data = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("example") as? NSData {
    if let example = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as? Word {
        example.meaning // ["abstractions", "generalizations", "use cases"]
        example.set // 2
        example.seen // 1
        example.word // "example"
    }
}
```

For further reading, Matt Thompson has an excellent post on the subject here:
http://nshipster.com/nscoding/

And it never hurts to read the official documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the structure in 'NSData' first usually does the trick for 'NSCoding' as it is then just treated as a sequence of bytes.

Or use 'Core Data' right away to make your life easier in the long run in regards to persistent storage of information.